# Image Gallery - mobile devices optimazation

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So i'm new to HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and JavaScript i made this gallery, it looks great but i need to fix it for mobile devices and smaller screens. What i should change?

Those #myImg4,5,12,13 are vertical images placed in differently because of design

PC preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLSwS.jpg

[and this is how it looks on smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAY8e.jpg)

BTW: I know, that code is very bad but i started with coding 4days ago so :/

I'm very thankful for every Respond!!!!
CSS Code for gallery is:

```
.gallerycontent {
  margin: 10px 200px 40px 100px;
}

.galleryhr {
  border-top: 2px solid #FF0000;
  width: 100;
}
.galleryhr h1 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;

}

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg , #myImg2 , #myImg3 , #myImg6 , #myImg7 , #myImg8 , #myImg9 , #myImg10 , #myImg11 , #myImg14 , #myImg15 , #myImg16 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;

}

#myImg4 {
  max-height: 414px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  right: 186px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg5 {
  max-height: 414px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  right: 511px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg12 {
  max-height: 414px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 590px;
  right: 511px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg13 {
  max-height: 414px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 590px;
  right: 186px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg3:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg4:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg5:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg6:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg7:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg8:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg9:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg10:hover {opacity: 0.7;}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }





}
```

Comment: Can you please post a viable example with the html?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/), you could do something like this in bootstrap v3:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-12'>
     <div class='col-lg-8'>
      <img class='img-responsive col-lg-4' src='image/path'/>
      <img class='img-responsive col-lg-4' src='image/path'/>
      <img class='img-responsive col-lg-4' src='image/path'/>
     </div>
     <div class='col-lg-4'>
      <img class='img-responsive col-lg-6' src='image/path'/>
      <img class='img-responsive col-lg-6' src='image/path'/>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and it should look good also on mobile.

Comment: i´ll try it, it looks logical to me. Thank You for Respond :)

Answer (score -1):

The culprit here is being 'too precise' with the positions. 
**Absolute positioned** items are not aware of their physical context. They don't know when they should occupy less space or go on a new row.

It's time to take a look at **Responsive Web Design**.
There are a couple of ways in which you can approach it.

- Float based layouts: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp
- Grid based layouts: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- Flex based layouts: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp

Start in this order.

Enjoy the process!